How to make objects transparent inside of another transparent object?
I'm trying to achieve a similar effect to the boolean modifier without using said modifier. I think the easiest way is to use a transparent object to affect the transparency of another object at its specific point.
I have a transparent object, I want the parts of a different object to also become transparent when inserted into the main transparent object.


@Sam_North As a general rule of thumb : try recreating what happens in real life. If there is an object inside another, that means the bigger object should have a geometry that stops at the surface of the smaller object. So that there is no overlap between objects.

I’m having a hard time understanding what you mean. Can you draw this and edit images into the question? MS Paint is fine as long as it’s ledgible.
